# How To Force An Entity Framework Query To Run?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I am displaying data in a WPF DataGrid using EF 6.  The data appears no problem.  But I call a FormatGrid function to do things like replace the underscores in field names with a space in the grid headers.  The first time I run a query it doesn't work.  It finds no columns in the DataGrid.  But after that when I run the query a second time it finds the columns and formats like I want.  I've tried setting LazyLoadingEnabled to false.  I've tried calling Count() on the query results.  Nothing gets the query populated during the first call.  Is there some way I can force the columns to load in an EF query, or is there a later event I should use in the grid to format the data?

```js
        private void LoadStores()
        {
            dgvStores.ItemsSource = null;
            using (var oContext = new FiduciaEntities())
            {
                oContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                var oQuery = from sd in oContext.StoreDefs
                             where sd.franchise == false
                             orderby sd.store_no
                             select new 
                             {
                                 Store_No = sd.store_no,
                                 Store_Name = sd.store_name,
                                 County = c.County1,
                                 _StoreID = sd.id
                             };

                dgvStores.ItemsSource = oQuery.ToList();
                dgvStores.SelectedValuePath = "_StoreID";
                int iCount = oQuery.Count();
                FormatGrid(ref dgvStores);
            }
        }
        private void FormatGrid(ref DataGrid oDataGrid)
        {
            foreach (DataGridColumn oColumn in oDataGrid.Columns)
            {
                string sHeader = oColumn.Header.ToString();
                if (sHeader.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (sHeader.Substring(0, 1) == "_")
                    {
                        oColumn.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                        oColumn.Header = oColumn.Header.ToString().Replace("_", "");
                    }
                }
                oColumn.Header = oColumn.Header.ToString().Replace("_", " ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: I found this page on MSDN which describes deferred execution in EF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Bb738633(v=VS.100).aspx.  It says when I call ToList() the query should be populated.  I guess the problem lies in the DataGrid.  I set AutoGenerateColumns to true, but the first time the grid loads it doesn't auto-generate the columns.  I don't know why.  It seems to be because it's in a different tab.  When I put a button on the tab and run the query from there it loads correctly the first time.  There may be no solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you verified if the problem is in the query not returning data or if the grid simply isn't displaying it. I would determine that first.

If you debug the code, putting a breakpoint on the line (where the query is actually run):

```
dgvStores.ItemsSource = oQuery.ToList();
```

Do you see any data returned after you run the first time?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, but it's not an elegant solution.  If someone has a better solution please post it.  I moved the FormatGrid code to the grid loaded event.  That seems to work.

```js
        private void dgvStores_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvStores.Columns.Count > 0)
            {
                DataGrid oDataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
                Utilities.FormatGrid(ref oDataGrid);
            }
        }
```

Comment: jstreet - Now that you mention it, it does look like your proposal.  Thanks.